# PDO update with optional values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to build a query string for updating some user info. My problem is `password` is optional (they update something, but not their password), `client` is optional and `phone` is optional.

I started with something like this

```
<?php
$sql = "UPDATE users SET username = :username, name = :name, email = :email ";

if (isset($request->password)) $sql .= ',password = :password';

if (isset($request->client)) $sql .= ',client = :client';

if (isset($request->phone)) $sql .= ',phone = :phone'

$q = $db->prepare($sql);
try
{
    $q->execute(array(
        "username"      => $request->username,
        "password"      => (isset($request->password)) ? md5($request->password) : '', //--not working yet, I know
        "name"          => $request->name,
        "client"        => (isset($request->client)) ? $request->client : '',
        "email"         => $request->email,
        "phone"         => (isset($request->phone)) ? $request->phone : ''
    ));
.....
?>
```

I am thinking there has to be a better way to do this with PDO. Also, I still have not incorporate into the query yet the `WHERE id = :idOfTheUserIamEditing`

Comment: Sidenote: Although you are using prepared statements, you should also be thinking about using a safer password hashing algo. MD5 is old (*circa 1992*) and considered broken. Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Looks fine to me. The fact that you're using prepared statements and named parameters is about as good as you can get.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I totally agree. I am aware md5 isn't secure. I had to get this project started asap with something to show in a very short amount of time. I would normally use bcrypt but this was just easier for the amount of time I had. I'll definitely change it down the road before production.

Comment: @Sammitch My issue is that I have to do a ton of if statements for the the three optional columns to be updated. I wasn't sure if something  `bindParam` could do would be a better route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, there isn't so many other ways to accomplish what you are trying to achieve. One thing I suggest is to build your array of parameters as you check the optional fields, this saves you from doing a "ton of if statement":

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET username = :username, name = :name, email = :email ";

$params = array();
//mandatory
$params[':username'] = $request->username;
$params[':name'] = $request->name;
$params[':email'] = $request->email;

//optional
if (isset($request->password)){
    $sql .= ',password = :password';
    $params[':password'] = $request->password;
}

if (isset($request->client)){
    $sql .= ',client = :client';
    $params[':client'] = $request->client;
}

if (isset($request->phone)){
    $sql .= ',phone = :phone';
    $params[':phone'] = $request->phone;
} 


try
{
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($params);
    ...
```

Comment: I'm actually doing this as you posted this. I'll report back if this ends up being the easiest

Comment: They will work the same, this way is just cleaner, and avoid messy ternary operator

Comment: `$params[":variable"]` - *Interesting*. I didn't know you could do that; *slick*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes it has the same effect as `array_push($params[":variable"], $variable);`

Comment: Ok, I have it working. This is essentially what I am doing now. I actually made a mistake, client and phone will be "mandatory" in a sense the user might want to remove client or phone from their profile so it updates regardless. The only if that came into play was for the password. Here is a pastie of the final script http://pastie.org/9456506

Comment: Seems a lot shorter also. Plus "uno" ;)